# What is the correct way to store a reference to this jquery object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Say, I want to grab a reference to several elements, I use a selector like this:

`$(input)` ... and then do something with it

But if I want to keep that reference, which one of these is the proper way?

`var el = $('input');`

`$el = $('input');`

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the variable being global or to it using a `$` prefix? Also, shouldn't your call be `$("input")`, with quotes?

Comment: Name your variables whatever you'd like, the dollarsign means nothing. The var keyword is a different matter, and should normally always be used, unless you are redeclearing.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - sorry about the syntax, jquery is a bit alien to me - now fixed. The variables will be contained inside a function, but maybe referenced several times within that function. The $ prefix on $el is just a naming convention I adopted to show it was a jquery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it all depends... example

```
function A() {
    var $el = $(input);
    function B() {
        $el = $(input2);
    }

    // $el here is $(input2)
} 

function C() {
    var $el = $(input);
    function D() {
        var $el = $(input2);
    }

    // $el here is $(input)
}
```

it all depends on your scope... so plan well...

Answer (score 3):

`var el = $(input);`   // Creates a local variable `el`

`$el = $(input);`   // Creates a global variable `$el`

`$` does nothing special but `var`

Using `$` at staring of variable name is just a convention to signify the variable is not ordinary variable but a jQuery object (or a collection of jQuery objects). Its not compulsory but a good habit.

But, if you wont put `var` , it will make the variable global.

Answer (score 1):

this will do that task for you

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    //var anchor = $(this);
    $anchor.fadeOut();
    //anchor.fadeOut();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
var el = $(input);
```

or

```
var $el = $(input);
```

Always use `var`. Using a `$` sign before the variable name is just something some people do to signify that it is a jQuery object, it's not necessary but can be useful in making your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct but difference is as below,

`var el = $(input);` this will create variable and assign value to it.

`$el = $(input);` this will assign value to previously defined variable in `global` or `local` scope.